# export data to csv in class from class python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python code that is used to pull data from azure methods.

```
for item in response:

    print(type(item))
    print(item)
    df = pd.DataFrame([item])
    print(df)
```

below is the print statements output.

```
 1. print(type(item)) :
     <class 'azure.mgmt.costmanagement.models._models_py3.SavingsPlanUtilizationSummary'>



2.print(item) : 
{'usage_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=<isodate.tzinfo.Utc object at 0x00000277D15A2D60>), 'avg_utilization_percentage': 95.83333333039417, 'min_utilization_percentage': 0.0}

3.print(df):
                                                   0
0  {'usage_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=<isodate.tzinfo.Utc object at 0x00000277D15A2D60>), 'avg_utilization_percentage': 95.83333333039417, 'min_utilization_percentage': 0.0}
```

Above Output I am getting but I am trying to export data into csv with different columns. How can I do that with correct date format as well. can you please help me?

Comment: Might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128934/pandas-dict-keys-to-columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to store all rows in the response to one CSV file.

```py
usage_statistics = pd.DataFrame([row for row in response])
usage_statistics.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

You can also use `date_format` parameter to format `datetime` objects as you want.

```py
usage_statistics.to_csv('output.csv', date_format='%Y%m%d', index=False)
```

Here is the content of the CSV file.

```
usage_date,avg_utilization_percentage,min_utilization_percentage
2022-12-26,95.83333333039417,0.0
```

Refer to the official document: [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for the codes of the format string.

Comment: it append everything thing to one column . how can i create separate column for usag_date,avg_utillization_percent…. etc)

Comment: They are in different columns indeed. Did you mean you want to store them in a transposed form?

Comment: I tried running but I am getting output like 0  {'usage_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=<isodate.tzinfo.Utc object at 0x00000277D15A2D60>), 'avg_utilization_percentage': 95.83333333039417, 'min_utilization_percentage': 0.0}

Comment: `0` in your output is the index of the row, not the column. Do you want to output the date into CSV or want to show the data in the terminal (by `print()`)?

Comment: I want data in csv .

Comment: i don’t know why it is not working for me.

Comment: Can you provide more information? What is the content of the output csv? What's your error message? What is the version of pandas?

Comment: there is no error it is just exporting data in one columns rather than creating multiple columns in csv

Comment: Can you copy paste the content of CSV to here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are not formatting `usage_date` when importing data from Azure. When importing data from azure, please convert datetime to dataframe after `.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` it will be fine. then you can convert it to csv file with `to_csv`.